# Each request of ajax give the data in response

Tags: jquery, ajax

The Following code give the same product id on each request
What is causing the problem.

This is form code which is associated with each product.

```
  <form  action="" method="" id="formproduct">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="productid" 
  value="<?php echo $row['Product-id'];?>" >
   <button  name="submit" class="btn">Add To Cart</button>
       </form>
```

This is the ajax requst code.

```
   var formData = {
        'product': jQuery(".productid").attr("value")
    };

jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server-cart.php",///contain the url of ajax 
            data:formData,
            dataType:"json",
```

Here i am getting the id from request.

```
 $id=$_REQUEST["product"];
```

Comment: Wouldn't be safer to access your input field value by id? $("#id").attr("value")?

Comment: why you want different product id? you have to `clear` data if saved success fully. Use `$("#productid").val("");` on every `ajax` `success` saved. your hidden field always present did not clear on next `save`.

Comment: what i am try to achieve is that on each ajax success my product id is added to session variable  declare.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple input fields with `class="productid"`?

Comment: @f_martinez yeah i have multiple input fields..

Comment: So , use `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: @f_martinez any help

Comment: You can find `closest(".productid")` from current row/click event. So it will give only that `form` `productid` only.

Comment: In your current code `.productid` gives always `first` `.productid` of your multiple `.productid`

Comment: @ComputerScience Tried stacksnippets at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34578345/ ? `.attr()` returns value set by `value="<?php echo $row['Product-id'];?>"` , not current value of `input` element

Comment: @ParthTrivedi already did but it did't solve the problem

Comment: @ParthTrivedi yeah it is giving me the first input value.
any way around it to get the respective input value.

Comment: @ComputerScience please check my answer. try it.

Comment: @guest271314 yeah i want to use this value
  `value="<?php echo $row['Product-id'];?>"`

Comment: @ComputerScience does this helpful to you?

Comment: @ComputerScience _"yeah i want to use this value value="<?php echo $row['Product-id'];?>""_  Can include full `html` at Question ? How is `$.ajax()` called ? At `.submit()` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you have multiple forms on your page with a number of different products. You have to rewrite your script to depend on correct form:

```
$("form").on("click", "button[name=submit]", function(){

    var form = $(this).closest("form"); // find the form to relate to
    var data = { product: $(".productid", form).val() }; // here we fetch product id from the input inside the form

    // do ajax-request
    // ...

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.attr()` returns original `value` set at `html` , `.val()` returns current `value` of `input` element. Try substituting `.val()` for `.attr()` , use `.change()` to retrieve current `value` of `input` element

```js
$("input").change(function() {
   // `$(this).attr("value")` : `123` : original `value` set at `input`
   // `$(this).val()` : current `value` of `input` element
   console.log($(this).val(), $(this).attr("value"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input value="123" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to like

here you have multiple forms i think

```
<form  action="" method="" id="formproduct">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="productid" 
  value="<?php echo $row['Product-id'];?>" >
   <button  name="submit" class="btn" onclick="saveProduct(this)">Add To Cart</button>
       </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function saveProduct(thisObj){
           //here we find productid value of current row 
           var formData = {
                  'product': jQuery(thisObj).closest(".productid").val();
                };

           jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server-cart.php",///contain the url of ajax 
            data:formData,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
            }
           });
}
```